# shader sun position - glsl

Tags: glsl, light

I am trying to make a shader that simulates the sun position and the light that it reflects in a object.

To simulate the sun trajectory I have a timer, and the light position is defined by:

```
fvLightPosition.x=-cos(Time)*speed;
fvLightPosition.y=sin(Time)*speed;
fvLightPosition.z=100.0;
```

The timer is a variable `float Time0_X`

I almost get the right trajectory, except that is upside down, and somehow look a bit weird. Can anyone give me a tip how to simulate the sun trajectory in the right way?

I am using RenderMonkey to make the shader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you scale your `Time` value so that it lies between `0` and `2*PI` radians (which corresponds to 0 and 180 degrees respectively). If your original `Time` value ranges from `0` to some number `MAX`, you can do the scaling like this: `(Time / MAX) * 2PI`.

I'm not sure what `speed` refers to, but you should most likely not be multiplying by that. The `cos` and `sin` values represent the X and Y components of the vector between the sun and the origin, so you should multiply by the distance of the sun from the centre of your scene, which is usually constant.